# jQuery how to get the class or id of last clicked element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get the class or an id of the last clicked element. This is what I have based off of what I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5905014/determine-last-item-clicked)...

**HTML**

```
<a href="" class="button">Button</a>
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.button').click(function () {
          myFuntion();
});

function myFunction (e) {
 e = e || event;
 $.lastClicked = e.target || e.srcElement;

 var lastClickedElement = $.lastClicked;
 console.log(lastClickedElement);

}
```

This sort of does what I want, but I am not sure how to go about modifying it so I can get just the class.

I have also tried using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9486936/get-the-id-of-the-last-clicked-jquery) solution but couldn't get it to work with my code.

```
$('.button').click(function () {
  myFuntion();
});


function myFunction(){
    var lastID;
    lastID = $(this).attr("id");

    console.log(lastID);
}
```

When I do this my console log comes back as undefined. I am probably missing something obvious. Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks everybody for the fast responses. I will look through these starting with the first reply and see if I can get anything to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass clicked element as parameter to your function:

```
$('.button').click(function () {
    myFunction(this);
});

function myFunction(element) {
    console.log(element);
    console.log(element.id);
    console.log($(element).attr("class"));
}
```

**UPDATE** added [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgrcn/)

Comment: Is it possible to do this for a class?

Comment: Sure, inside `myFunction`: `console.log($(element).attr("class"));`

Comment: Okay this is very close to what I want to do and everything seems to work.

Comment: I would like to maybe make the click handler simpler something like $('.button').click(myFunction); ... But this is good I can make this work. I felt like it should be basic but I wasn't sure what I needed exactly. thanks for your help.

Comment: Well, it turns that you can do this, I wasn't fully aware of this. Check this [jsfiddle snippet](http://jsfiddle.net/Xgrcn/4/) and don't be afraid to experiment :P

Comment: This was where I was trying to get. So thanks again.. http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/Xgrcn/7/

Answer (score 1):

A couple of ways come to mind:

```
$(".button").click(myFunction);
```

Should work with the above `myFunction`.

---

```
$(".button").click(function () { myFunction($(this)); });
function myFunction($elem) {
   var lastID;
   lastID = $elem.attr('id');
   $.data('lastID', lastID);
}
```

Comment: I tried this and I get a console error.. Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'attr' ... Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/cFgWD/

Comment: I am trying class instead of ID... I will double check, but I think I get the same error regardless

Comment: I get this error ... Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'attr' ..

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the class-name of the element, assuming you have an accurate reference to the element from which you want to retrieve the data:

```
var lastClickedElement = $.lastClicked,
    lastClickedElementClassNames = lastClickedElement.className;
```

This does return the full list of all the classes of the element though.

Comment: I tried this with what I have and I get the whole HTML element in my console.log .. Here is my fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/krishollenbeck/hZh9B/5/

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.button').click(function () {
  myFuntion(this);
});


function myFunction(ele){
    var lastID;
    lastID = $(ele).attr("id");

    console.log(lastID);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First Select all possible DOM Elements

```
 var lastSelectedElement = null

    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("*").live("click",function(){
       lastSelectedElement = $(this);
       myFunction($(this));
      });
    });

   function myFunction(element) {
console.log(element);
console.log(element.id);
console.log($(element).attr("class"));
 }
```

than you could play with `lastSelectedElement` by grabbing it's ID or Class with jQuery `.attr("ID OR CLASS");`